# Spring boot Cookie based authentication does not work on mobile browsers

Tags: spring-boot, cookies, mobile, browser

Dears, I have an issue with spring boot app - I'm using a cookie based authentication there and it works fine for desktop browsers.
But it does not work for mobile browsers as the cookie is not saved and therefore authentication fails.
App adress: [vvbeautyapp on heroku](https://vvbeautyapp.herokuapp.com) 
The code I use to set cookie while authenticated is simple:

```
response.addCookie(securityCookie);
response.addHeader("token", "token");
```

Where Cookie is import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;.
Then in my controller I'm trying to get that cookie:

```
@CookieValue(value = "token", required = false) String token
```

but it is not found as the cookie does not saves...
I've tried it on mobile browsers Opera and Chrome on Xiaomi Redmi Note 4x.
The desired behaviour would be that the cookie is stored in mobile browsers just like on desktop browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the solution turned out to be quite easy :) In css for mobile (as it is RWD) there was an error - it was making every mark uppercase (text-transform: uppercase;) no mater what user wanted to enter and the password was not matching which was obviously causing an error on authentication...